# wpf-how to provide user authentication for login page

Tags: sql-server, wpf

i need to develop a login page using wpf.How to autenticate users who login by refering to data in microsoft sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a little more information on what you are doing? Are you using ASPNETDB role provider service for authentication or are you just storing a username and password in SQL? How are you planing on going at the data? Do you have a stored procedure on SQL that will be called and the value from teh WPF app passes as parameters or are you planning on connecting via a WCF service? Or are you planning on creating the SQL connection directly from the WPF app and passing the values to SQL via code? 
Programatically authenticion can be handled in a similar fashion as a winform or even asp.net app your controls are just a bit different but code-wise it can be very similar.
The difference is in how you plan on connecting to the the database.

Provide a few more requirements and we should be able to help you get a poc up and running.